# How to scan directories within directories in a PHP loop

Tags: php, loops, scandir

```
$dirs = scandir("../public_html/");

$subDirArr=array();

foreach ($dirs as $currentIndex => $currentDir) {


    if (is_dir($currentDir))
        if (!($currentDir[0] == "."))
            echo "<a href='../public_html/$currentDir'>$currentDir</a><br/>";


}
```

So I've got this code that scans my public_html directory on my server and echos out all the subdirectories (but not the files) so that I have a list of clickable links to my subdirectories.

What I want to do is when one of the directories is clicked, have it show IT'S subdirectories (if any).  I can't figure out how to logically do that though.  I could write a loop within a loop within a loop, etc, but I want this code to work no matter how many directories I add.

How could I accomplish this?

The endgoal is to have a menu system for my hosting files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. You can adjust function to whatever needed:

```
function getDirs($root)
{
    foreach (scandir($root) as $dir) {
        if ( ! in_array($dir, ['.', '..'])) {
            $path = realpath($root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir);
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                echo $path . PHP_EOL;
                getDirs($path);
            }
        }
    }
}

getDirs("../public_html/");
```

Comment: Now I just need to try and understand that...I'm extremely new to PHP :P

Comment: @EricDavidSartor http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion this can help you to understand recursion